# Get opcounters by database

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a monitoring script that looks something like this

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
for database in client.database_names():
    iterator = client[database].command({"serverStatus":1})["opcounters"].iteritems()
    for key, value in iterator:
        log(key, data=value, database=database)
```

This has been giving me the same result for all of my opcounters.  Looking at my graphs, I get data like this:

```
opcounters.command_per_second on test_database: 53.32K
opcounters.command_per_second on log_database: 53.32K
```

Obviously, "serverStatus" is indicative of the entire server, not just the database.

Is it possible to get opcounters for each database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no per-database opcounts, at least for v2.8.0 or earlier. The op-counter structure that is used in *serverStats* is a global one. Each new count is recorded without the context of which db or collection was involved.

As an small aside the *collStats* command does not have op statistics at all so it wont be possible to calculate a database's total ops by aggregation either.

There's an open feature request you can watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-2178: Track stats per db/collection](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2178).